# auto partial page refresh in asp.net without UpdatePanel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I want to make auto partial page refresh in asp.net. There is UpdatePanel but it sends too much data. So I've found that I can make a webservice and call it by the JavaScript code. But I don't know how to call webservice automatic. There are many examples showing how to call webservice by the button click event:

http://www.asp.net/ajax/videos/how-do-i-make-client-side-network-callbacks-with-aspnet-ajax

How to do this by the interval? Am I going in good direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) function:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    // code here will be called every 10 seconds
}, 10000);
```

To reset automatic calls you could use the [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearInterval) function on the `id` returned by the `setInterval`.