# automatic scroll and paginate the gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am working on asp.net 3.5 and C#.

I have a list with 100 record and show them in a gridview. We see information on a monitor so user wont exists for changing pages or scroll to end. I need code that on regular time intervals change pages to show all records.

How can I do it?

Comment: noone is going to "send you teh codez". That's not how SO works... You should show what you have attempted so far....

Comment: I will suggest you to give a search option rather than auto paging.

Comment: @ krshekhar : please read question: "We will see this informations on a monitor so user wont exists for changing pages"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of many ways to auto-refresh a page, using [`meta refresh`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10">
```

Where 10 is the page refresh interval in seconds.

The server can determine which page to serve, based on previous page served.

> Use of meta refresh is discouraged by the World Wide Web Consortium
>   (W3C), since unexpected refresh can disorient users. Meta refresh also
>   impairs the web browser's "back" button in some browsers ...
>
> There are legitimate uses of meta-refresh, such as providing updates
>   to dynamic web pages or implementing site controlled navigation of a
>   website without JavaScript. Many large websites use it to refresh news
>   or status updates, especially when dependencies on JavaScript and
>   redirect headers are unwanted.

Another option is to use javascript, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007724/auto-partial-page-refresh-in-asp-net-without-updatepanel).

Comment: thanks for youre reply,I want do exactly like this:http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/DataBinding/Live.aspx

Comment: so what's stopping you?

Comment: @MitchWheat, good job helping a difficult case. user1312204, no one will go more than half-way for you. If you craft your questions better, do some research, you will find this is a great forum.

Comment: I dont know how do it:( i just know how fill gridview ,but I cant do anything for changing automatically

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1821753.aspx/1
this link solved my problem